# Find correct object names in server side errors

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just realized if I don't put my asp.net controls inside a form with `runtat="server"` attribute I will get a error like this:

> Control 'ctl25' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with
>   runat=server

Although its really easy to debugging this error I'm just curious is it possible to understand which object is `ctl25`? Because I searched carefully all object attributes, `.aspx`, `.aspx.cs` and `.aspx.designer.cs` files but I couldn't find anything with `ctl25` label.

So is it possible to find `ctl25` referring to which object?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, yes, it seems my button didnt had an ID and asp.net generated 'ctl25' for it automatically, that is why I couln't find 'ctl25' any where in my fiels :) I gave an ID to my button and now I can see it in my error message.

Comment: sry, I did create an answer to enhance communication ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, setting `ID` is somewhat optional (server-side-access can be achieved by iterating over `Controls`-property of parent, and client-side-access just needs `ClientID`, which is done automatically), by leveraging on the automatic `ClientID`-setting.
So there's a fairly good chance that you'll never see `ID="ctl25"` as it might be/is done automagically.

Just give the control in question an explicit `ID`, and you should be fine.